Driving stepper motor
I got a few stepper motors (NEMA-17) from an old 3D printer, I wanted to drive these motors with a uC.
I set up my circuit with DRV8825, ESP32, and a stepper motor using a 100uF capacitor between the terminals of the voltage source, and dir is set to HIGH as I just want to see it rotate in one direction.
Using full step mode (M0-M1-M2 all low), I have been playing with the pulse frequency. When I use a pulse every 1s, the motor rotates once clockwise and once counter-clockwise (dir is fixed), when I use a pulse every 2ms, the motor rotates but makes lots of vibrations, finally a pulse every 1.6 ms the one where the motor rotates properly and with least noise.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
While all of this has been a trial and error process, I want to know what is the ideal way to know the right frequency to drive the stepper motor at. How to get the best speed vs torque?
I also tried to change to micro-stepping modes, but I failed to find a pulse frequency to drive the motor properly in one direction.

Your phase sequence is wrong if it goes CW  then CCW with no Dir change. You ought to able to step a few hundred Hz using acceleration using 200 steps/ Rev. The low ESR bulk cap goes across the driver not the motor.

Yes, I assumed that is the case; but as I am just driving the DR8825 step and not the motor itself, what could it be that I am doing wrong? I can see it has something to do with the way frequency, but what is the rule here?
Example-> pulse on ste[ -> FULL STEP expected on the motor driven by DR8825, another pulse I expect the same thing; so I was thinking that I am just going to control the speed, the driver would handle the phase and writing the correct sequence to moror, right ?
Capacitor is connected to voltage source, not the motor.

Full steps must advance every step in the same direction if connected properly. This is the fastest yet noisiest.  Sorry I misread motor||cap

Unless you show your work, it is hard to pinpoint.(!)

What details would you like to know?
From the hardware side, I think the setup is correct as I was able to drive the motor at one stage with some noise and vibrations with a pulse every 1.6ms. At least I think this proves that connectivity is correct, right?
The only thing left is the software if we agree on the previous point, in here I drive the pin high, wait for TIME_PULSE_LENGTH/2, drive it low,
wait for TIME_PULSE_LENGTH/2 .

A very warm welcome to the site. Please can you edit your question and add a schematic, as your text description needs every reader to try and draw it in their heads without any datasheets. The schematic editor here is straightforward to use. Thanks.

(Edit -> CTRL+M to open up the Schematic Editor)

Check if your code for coil current is in quadrature sequence with two half steps per full step. You ought to be able to do sequential full steps at any speed until it slips from acceleration, a , or max velocity mm/s or Hz.  Try 10 Hz with 200 full steps then reverse repeat same, again.

But this time domain programming is primitive,  when you use a CNC Shield and gcode-compiled Arduino, you can program in Gcode for position from Windows (Gcode Panel, free) for any 2D or 3D  path with velocity and acceleration factors instead of worrying about  wrong phase sequences or half or 1/N steps

Whether at 1s or 2 ms or 1.6 ms intervals, I'd expect it to rotate.
It looks to me like one of your wires is not connected properly.
If only B1 and B2, or A1 and A2, are connected, it would explain the erratic behavior, as a single coil could push the rotor one way or the other.
If you have a multimeter, you can easily measure each pin (directly on the motor) and verify that there's indeed a signal on it. (Just use a slow frequency like <1Hz so the multimeter has time to measure.)
Better yet, if you have one, with an oscilloscope you could measure the whole sequence.
Otherwise, I'd verify the cabling, possibly replacing it. Assuming you're using jumper wires, I'd just immediately replace them as they are rather fragile in my experience.
And to actually answer your question of

How to get the best speed vs torque?

It depends on the driver, the motor and the load. There's often a graph of it in datasheets, but you can measure it yourself. It's always a good idea to test your setup rather than blindly trust datasheets and your calculations anyway. To test it:
Put your load on it, then try doing a full rotation (probably 200 steps, but I haven't check your motor datasheet).
If it did indeed turn 360°, that means no step was skipped. Increase the frequency until you don't get a full turn. Decrease the frequency until it doesn't skip anymore (with some margin), and that's your max speed for your load.
Repeat with a variety of loads to get the full curve of speed VS torque curve.
